# Vertical line and text

Tags: margins, marginpar, marginnote, line, vertical

I am trying to insert a vertical line and some text or image in the margin as in the picture no matter if it is an image or a text with several lines [image]

However the source code embeds the line and text in all pages and the text after the \begin{document} is too narrow.

Thanks for the support

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[all]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\SetBgContents{Text here but with several lines}% Set contents
\SetBgPosition{-0.0cm,1.5cm}% Select location
\SetBgOpacity{1.0}% Select opacity
\SetBgAngle{0.0}% Select rotation of logo
\SetBgScale{1.0}% Select scale factor of logo

\newlength{\leftrule}
\newlength{\rightrule}
\setlength{\leftrule}{2\leftmargin-\marginparsep}
\setlength{\rightrule}{2\leftmargin+\textwidth+\marginparsep}
 \AddToShipoutPicture{%
\AtPageLowerLeft{%
\put(\LenToUnit{\leftrule},0){\rule{0.3pt}{\paperheight}}  % Rule on the left
%\put(\LenToUnit{\rightrule},0){\rule{1pt}{\paperheight}}  % Rule on the right
}
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code example is not compilable. It throws several errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the `fancyhdr` package for that. See the example. It surely contains many hardcoded constants, so it could be done better.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,draft]{article}
\usepackage[all]{background}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\pictureOne{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw[red] (0,0)--(0,2)--(2,2)--(2,0)--cycle;\end{tikzpicture}}
\def\pictureTwo{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw[blue] (0,0)--(0,2)--(2,2)--(2,0)--cycle;\end{tikzpicture}}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\def\headrulewidth{0pt}
\newlength{\ruleheight}
\setlength{\ruleheight}{\textheight}
\addtolength{\ruleheight}{20mm}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{%
    \vbox to 0pt{%
    \vskip 5mm \hbox{%
        \hskip-5mm\vrule height\ruleheight%
        \hskip-25mm\vbox to \ruleheight{\pictureOne\vss\pictureTwo}}%
        \vss}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\footnotesize\thepage}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're code already uses commands of `eso-pic` for the rule. You can use it for the rule and text. With the star form `\AddToShipoutPicture*` the contents will be added only to the next/current page, that will be shipped out.

Package `picture` eliminates the need of using `\LenToUnit` for length/dimensions in the position arguments of picture commands like `\put`. I also use e-TeX primitive `\dimexpr` to calculate some dimensions.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{% star form for add to next shipout only
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \put(\dimexpr
    \oddsidemargin+1in-\marginparsep\relax,0){\rule{0.3pt}{\paperheight}}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \put(\marginparsep,-\baselineskip){%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \oddsidemargin+1in-3\marginparsep}{%
        Text here but with several lines}%
    }%
  }%
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

The `\parbox` allows to use several lines of text. If you want an image only, you can use `\makebox` to center it in the margin:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{eso-pic,picture}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{% star form for add to next shipout only
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \put(\dimexpr
    \oddsidemargin+1in-\marginparsep\relax,0){\rule{0.3pt}{\paperheight}}%
  }%
  \AtPageUpperLeft{%
    \put(\marginparsep,-\baselineskip){%
      \parbox[t]{\dimexpr \oddsidemargin+1in-3\marginparsep}{%
        Text here but with several lines}%
    }%
  }%
  \AtPageLowerLeft{%
    \put(\marginparsep,-\baselineskip){%
      \makebox(\dimexpr \oddsidemargin+1in-3\marginparsep,5cm)[c]{%
        \includegraphics[width=2cm,height=3cm]{example-image}%
      }
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image: one page with margin contents]